# Search for all values 'greater than' and operate (subtraction)

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, subtraction

I'm new to Python and starting to build a small and short simulation scenario for pallet movements.

So basically I have an array "storage client" which accumulates pallets until it reaches a number (120) and then ships it back to the warehouse.

At one point it's kind of like this:

```
Shipper_Leaving = 0
Storages = [80, 140, 2, 43, 121]

if any (y>120 for y in Storages):
    Shipper_Leaving[y] = Shipper_Leaving + 120
##Storages - [0,120,0,0,120]
##print storages 
[80, 120, 2, 43, 1]
```

And then I'm stuck (at the #'s)... I'm trying to find how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks! Mainly that when a client's storage hits 120 or greater, to reduce it by 120 (full truck back) and increase the warehouse storage by the return shipment which is later down the code but not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this simple solution helps you:

```
Shipper_Leaving = 0
Storages = [80, 140, 2, 43, 121]
for i in range(len(Storages)):
    if Storages[i]>=120:
        Shipper_Leaving+=120
        Storages.remove(i)
print(Shipper_Leaving)
```

With the info that you've provided, it seems like you want to know how many elements are above or = 120?

Comment: Thanks!
Actually the idea is that when the storage hits 120 or over, to send a truck with pallets back to the warehouse. So your code would work but still needs to update the local storage (an element of the array)... so it would have to include something like: (line 6) Storage [i] = Storage [i] - 120

Comment: @Wilhelm, oh that's easy. You can use a python keyword "remove" for that. I've updated the code. Checkout [https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/remove](this link), hope this helps.